# How to generate time zone in P05:30 format in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I used the below mentioned function to generate P05:30 format time zone in jmeter but Jmeter was unable to print the time zone.

```bash
${__groovy(java.time.ZonedDateTime.now(java.time.ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", java.time.ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(5, 30))).format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")),)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the comma to create a correct syntax

```bash
${__groovy(java.time.ZonedDateTime.now(java.time.ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC"\, java.time.ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(5\, 30))).format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")),)}
```

and if you want to show the zone info, use character `z`

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'z
```